# Apache Flink BlobStore Not Getting Cleared, Leading to Storage Full Error

Tags: java, apache-flink, apache-beam

I am working on a project using Apache Flink and I am encountering an issue where the BlobStore is not getting cleared as expected. This is causing the storage to fill up and eventually leading to a java.io.IOException: No space left on device error.

Here is the stack trace:

```
2024-03-01 11:44:12,716 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler              [] - File upload failed.
org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostRequestDecoder$ErrorDataDecoderException: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.loadDataMultipart(HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.java:1371) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.5.jar:1.13.5]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.getFileUpload(HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.java:905) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.5.jar:1.13.5]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.decodeMultipart(HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.java:551) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.5.jar:1.13.5]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.parseBodyMultipart(HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.java:442) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.5.jar:1.13.5]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.parseBody(HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.java:411) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.5.jar:1.13.5]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.offer(HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.java:336) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.5.jar:1.13.5]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.offer(HttpPostMultipartRequestDecoder.java:53) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.5.jar:1.13.5]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostRequestDecoder.offer(HttpPostRequestDecoder.java:223) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.5.jar:1.13.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler.channelRead0(FileUploadHandler.java:146) [flink-dist_2.12-1.13.5.jar:1.13.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler.channelRead0(FileUploadHandler.java:69) [flink-dist_2.12-1.13.5.jar:1.13.5]
    at org.apache
```

We encountered a memory leak issue in the Apache Beam library beam-sdks-java-core. This issue was rectified in the 2.54.0 release. We initially suspected that this memory leak was causing the JVM of the Flink Job Manager to shut down, which in turn, was preventing the BlobStore from being cleared. However, despite upgrading to the fixed version of the Beam library, we continue to face the same issue with the BlobStore. For reference, the memory leak issue can be found at this link: https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/29890.

We have upgraded the Beam version and since then, we haven't encountered any OutOfMemory errors. However, we plan to conduct further testing to confirm this improvement. Despite the upgrade, we're still facing an issue where the BlobStore is not being cleared as expected. We're uncertain about the potential causes of this issue beyond the previously suspected memory leak. Any insights or suggestions to help us troubleshoot this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Further investigation suggest that memory leak in JDK 1.8 causing files in blobStore not being released. The issue has been reported here https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8013099 but it was resolved in JDK 1.9 and above and not back ported to 1.8. More testing is needed but this blobStore issue might be resolved just by updating the JDK